# Unable to understand AWS Fargate Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

We have a requirement of deploying Redis as an External Load Balancer Service on AWS-EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service). As Redis will be a statefulset which of the following combination will be the best fit with EKS -

- EKS with Self-managed nodes
- EKS with Managed Node Groups
- EKS with AWS Fargate

Although, I have studied that AWS Fargate should be used for deploying stateless applications.

> Fargate, thus far, has been ideal for running stateless containerized workloads in a secure and cost-effective manner. Secure because Fargate runs each pod in a VM-isolated environment and patches nodes automatically. Cost-effective because, in Fargate, you only pay for the compute resources you have configured for your pod.

I didn't understand how stateless applications will be cost-effective. Kindly verify the below statement. It would be quite helpful.

> In the stateless applications, the container will be in the running state, when there will be requests and otherwise no. of instances will be 0 just as in GCP Cloud Run.
> Whereas in the stateful ones, the container will be running every time. And for this reason, we should use, EC2 instances for stateful applications

Comment: Cost-effective in this context means that you won't pay for idle time (depending on how long the Fargate Container is running). Statefulness refers to the application that you run, e.g., using sessions within the application (not cache). For example, if you're using JWT for authentication, and redis for the cache, you can generally consider your application as stateless.

Comment: In general, you could use Fargate for stateful application as well if you have attached and shared volume such EBS, EFS, etc. However, if you're looking for cost optimization; it doesn't mean Fargate is cheaper then EC2 ALWAYS. There's an AWS [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/theoretical-cost-optimization-by-amazon-ecs-launch-type-fargate-vs-ec2/) that cost comparison of EC2 vs fargate. In my case, I could reduce the cost $6K ish monthly for particular project since I migrated a service from EC2 to Fargate.